# Azure Automation Account using Managed Identity across Multiple subscription

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-managed-identity

Azure Automation Account using Managed Identity across Multiple subscription.
I have tried using Azure Automation but it's not working across subscription.
I tried fetching using Get Az Subscription but it's not working.
I tried searching over the documentation but not helped.
Anyone having idea to implement Azure Automation Runbook across subscription(Other than RunAs Account as it's going to be deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

Runas account getting depreciated so managed identity using.
Refer link below to add multiple subscription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1035007/azure-automation-account-using-managed-identity-ac.html